# Progressbar does not reach 100%

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, progress-bar

I have three nested "for" loops in which I perform some operations. I want to update a progress so that it starts when the the outermost loop starts and it ends when the the outermost loop end.
This is an example of what I did:

```
for (int x= front; x<= back; x++)
{
 for (int y= top; y<= bottom; y++)
  {
   for (int z= left; z<= right; z++)
    {
      //operations
    }
   } 
   uploadProgressView.UpdateProgressTo((100 * (float)(x- front)) / (back - front + 1));
 }
```

where:

```
public void UpdateProgressTo(int value)
{
    progress.Value = value;
    progress.Refresh();
    Application.DoEvents(); 
}
```

I obtain that the progress does not reach 100%.
The progress **ProgressBar.Maximum** is set to 100 and the **ProgressBar.Step** is set to 1.
I have logged the values of the progress and I obtained exactly what I expect:

```
0
1,333333
2,666667
4
5,333333
6,666667
8
9,333333
10,66667
12
13,33333
14,66667
16
17,33333
18,66667
20
21,33333
22,66667
24
25,33333
26,66667
28
29,33333
30,66667
32
33,33333
34,66667
36
37,33333
38,66667
40
41,33333
42,66667
44
45,33333
46,66667
48
49,33333
50,66667
52
53,33333
54,66667
56
57,33333
58,66667
60
61,33333
62,66667
64
65,33334
66,66666
68
69,33334
70,66666
72
73,33334
74,66666
76
77,33334
78,66666
80
81,33334
82,66666
84
85,33334
86,66666
88
89,33334
90,66666
92
93,33334
94,66666
96
97,33334
98,66666
```

Why the progress does not reach the 100% even though the values are well calculated, I force the refresh of progress and I call **Application.DoEvents()** every time I update the progress value?
I've tryed to replace this line

```
uploadProgressView.UpdateProgressTo((100 * (float)(x- front)) / (back - front + 1));
```

with this

```
uploadProgressView.UpdateProgressTo((125 * (float)(x- front)) / (back - front + 1));
```

and the progress reach 100% but, if I change the operations inside the inner "for" loop I need a much bigger value than 125 to see the progress advancing to the end. 
How can I set this value in order to fix this problem regardless of the operations in the inner loop?

Thank you

Comment: If you try to update from UI thread your application will not show anything till it finishes processing, that could be the reason why it shows 100% progress. You can use a BackgroundWorker as the link shared by Aron.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your method UpdateProgressTo is supposed to set the progress to the value sent.

so it should be 
progress.Value = value; 
(instead of the +=)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the text, in my code there is progress.Value = value. I'm editing it. Other ideas? Thank you